# SQL Select data by this week

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi how do I get the data by current week?

Select * from Transaction where transactionDate ....

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? (It may offer special features around this.)

Comment: Hi i am using microsoft access

Comment: @newbie123: lesson here is make sure you specify the database when asking a SQL question. Most of the answers you got are not applicable to your problem because you didn't specify the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SQL Server based on week of year. Please see [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) for @@DATEFIRST etc. for example, this is all trades since Sunday in US/UK settigs:

```
WHERE DATEPART(week, transactionDate) = DATEPART(week, GETDATE())
```

Edit:

For Access, use *this* [DatePart](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datepart.php) and use "ww" for the part of date you want.
In answer to the comment, "week" is not a variable; it's the bit of the date you want

So:

```
WHERE DatePart("ww", transactionDate) = DatePart("ww", GETDATE())
```

Comment: DATEPART(week, transactionDate) sothe week variable what should i enter?

Comment: I think this answer must be from before the ms-access tag was added because a large part of it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Access

Last *n* days:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction 
WHERE transactionDate >=Date()-7
```

If you have indexes and this type of difference suits, it will be faster because it is [`sargable`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

This week by week difference:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction 
WHERE DateDiff("w",[transactionDate],Date())=0
```

BTW It is considered bad practice to use *

DateDiff: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/ha012288111033.aspx

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the term "sargable", though I'm not certain it's better than just saying "can use indexes".

Answer (score 0):

Simple but portable:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Transaction
    WHERE transactionDate >= ?
      AND transactionDate <= ?
```

Calculate the two parameters in your server-side code to whatever definition of 'week' you need.

Answer (score 0):

In IBM DB2

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction
WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 7 days AND CURRENT TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

mySQL (standard date stamp)

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction
WHERE WEEK(NOW())=WEEK(transactionDate);
```

mySQL (unix timestamp stamp)

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction
WHERE WEEK(NOW())=WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(transactionDate));
```

Bit of a unoptimized query. Could be a more efficient way.

Note: This isn't a rolling 7 days. Just the current week of the year.

EDIT: Sorry I didn't see the ms-access tag. ignore all of this :|

Comment: like @gbn said:

WHERE DATEPART("ww", transactionDate) = DATEPART("ww", GETDATE())

week should be replaced by "ww"

Answer (score 0):

In Access, if you want to run a query to find records that fall in the current week, use

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE table.DateField Between (Date()-Weekday(Date())+1) And (Date()-Weekday(Date())+7);
```

That runs Sunday through Saturday. Use +2 and +6 instead if you want the workweek.

Comment: Depends on how you define "current week", don't you think? Do you mean the last 7 days? Inclusive of today, or before today? Or, the week today is in starting on Monday? Or Sunday?